# Correct if absdiff() the same image (just slightly shifted vertically) the difference is > 15%?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

If I have 2 images that are pretty much exactly the same (except one image has all its pixels shifted 2 pixels up) and I compare them using `cv2.absdiff()` the difference is > 15%. That doesn't sound right to me?

I was thinking the difference would be much lower. Is this correct? Or is my maths incorrect?

Below is my code:

```
def calculate_difference_measure():
    # Load in same image twice
    img1 = cv2.imread('./i1.png')
    img2 = img1.copy()

    # Translate one image slightly up
    img2 = imutils.translate(img2, 0, 2)
    
    # Difference the 2 images and get all values below 15
    diff = cv2.absdiff(img1, img2)
    gray_diff = cv2.cvtColor(diff, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    thresh_diff = cv2.threshold(gray_diff, 15, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]
    
    # Calculate the difference between the 2 images
    total_pixels = img1.shape[0] * img1.shape[1] * 1.0
    diff_on_pixels = cv2.countNonZero(thresh_diff) * 1.0
    difference_measure = diff_on_pixels / total_pixels
    # Outputs 'difference_measure: 0.1768186919702071'
    print('difference_measure: {}'.format(difference_measure))
```

Test image that my code uses to compare.
[image]:

Comment: Seems that there's nothing wrong with your code, the math is correct. Your binary threshold maybe too sensitive (too low), but other than that, all seems correct. Perhaps you need an alternative similarity measurement?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, as far as I understood from the documentation of cv2.absdiff, it calculates the difference of pixels. to visualize i created a chessboard and shifted 1 row - that resulted in 100% difference.

```py
import cv2
import imutils
import numpy as np


def calculate_difference_measure(img1: np.array, img2: np.array) -> float:
    diff = cv2.absdiff(img1, img2)
    thresh_diff = cv2.threshold(diff, 15, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]

    # Calculate the difference between the 2 images
    total_pixels = img1.shape[0] * img1.shape[1] * 1.0
    diff_on_pixels = cv2.countNonZero(thresh_diff) * 1.0
    difference_measure = diff_on_pixels / total_pixels
    print('difference_measure: {}'.format(difference_measure))
    return difference_measure


def main():
    chess1 = np.uint8(([150, 50] * 4 + [50, 150] * 4) * 4).reshape((8, 8))
    chess2 = imutils.translate(chess1.copy(), 0, 1)

    calculate_difference_measure(img1=chess1, img2=chess1)  # 0 diff
    calculate_difference_measure(img1=chess1, img2=chess2)  # 1 diff (100% different)

    chess1 = cv2.resize(chess1, (400, 400), interpolation=cv2.INTER_AREA)
    chess2 = cv2.resize(chess2, (400, 400), interpolation=cv2.INTER_AREA)
    cv2.imshow('original', chess1)
    cv2.imshow('translated', chess2)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
    return


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

[image]